# Periodically (monthly) delete files in a specific folder

Tags: joomla-3.x

I am wondering if there is a way (script/extension) to delete files from a folder after a certain file has reached the age of 30 days. For example, I have a folder which receives uploaded files daily. I want the files that have been there for 30 days to be deleted.

Comment: Yes, of course this can be done.  However, you have posted a "requirements dump" in a community where support is free, but often the people who provide this support are actually paid, professional Joomla developers/administrators.  It is a sign of respect to these people, to include (in your question) the research that you've already conducted, extensions in the JED that you have seen/tried, and any attempts you've made to add a script to a scheduled cronjob.  Please [edit] your question so that it does look like you are asking for paid professionals to hand over a solution that they normally

Answer (score 1):

If your Joomla website is hosted on a Linux or Unix server, then you could create a cron job (a scheduled process) to run the following command every night:

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
```

It will find and remove ("rm") all files in the folder that you specify and that have a modified time ("mtime") that is older than 30 days.